# Web server - how to parse requests? Asynchronous Stream Tokenizer?

Tags: http, parsing, asynchronous, stream, tokenize

I'm attempting to create a simple webserver in C# in asynchronous socket programming style.  The purpose is very narrow - a Comet server (http long-polling).

I've got the windows service running, accepting connections, dumping request info to the Console and returning simple fixed content to the client.

Now, I can't figure out a manageable strategy for parsing the request data asynchronously and safely.  I've written synchronous LL1 parsers before.  I'm not sure if LL1 Parser is appropriate or necessary for HTTP.  I don't know how to tokenize the input stream asynchronously.  All I can think of is having an input buffer per client, reading into that, then copying that to a StringBuilder and periodically checking to see if I have a complete request.  But that seems inefficient and might led to difficult to debug/maintain code.

Also, there are the two phases of the connection of receiving the request in full and the sending a response - in this case, after some delay.  Once the request is validated and actionable, only then am I planning to enroll the connection in the long-polling manager.  However, a misbehaving client could continue to send data and fill up a buffer, so I think I need to continue to monitor and empty the input stream during the response phase, right?

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

I guess the first step is knowing whether it is possible to efficiently tokenize a network stream asynchronously and without a large intermediate buffer.  Even without a proper parser, the same challenges of creating a tokenizer apply to reading "lines" of input at a time, or even reading until double blank lines (one big token).  I don't want to read one byte at a time from the network, but neither do I want to read too many bytes and have to store them in some intermediate buffer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTTP the best way is reading the headers in memory completely (until you receive `\r\n\r\n`) and then simply splitting by `\r\n` to get the headers and every header by `:` to separate name and value.

There's no need to use a complex parser for that.

Comment: Thanks.  What's a good way to check for that sequence resilient to the case when it straddles buffered reads?  When it the request *too* long?  Do I need to keep emptying the input stream after that point or can I safely ignore additional input without worrying about a buffer filling up and affecting other connections?